# Failed to Fetch Updates for pop os

Tags: package-management, upgrade, pop-os

When I try to update my pop os I gotten a failed fetch update and I don't know what I am really doing since I am new to linux. This is this what the details of the failed update shown me:

```
E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/21.04/prod jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US.UTF-8) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:5
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:5
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:5
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:5
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:5
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US.UTF-8) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:5
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:5
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:5
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:5
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:5
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:5
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:5
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:5
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:5
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:7
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:7
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:7
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:7
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:7
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US.UTF-8) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:7
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:7
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:7
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:7
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:7
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:7
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:7
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:7
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:7
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US.UTF-8) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US.UTF-8) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: GPG error: https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY DFA175A75104960E
E: The repository 'https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease' is not signed.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease is not (yet) available (The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY DFA175A75104960E)
```

Comment: What did you do to end up in this situation? Seems like you messed up the paket source configuration. Why do you have e.g. the Microsoft Ubuntu repo?

Comment: I don't know, I am a complete novice in linux so I might have downloaded something unnecessary somewhere down the line